VBA - Wanted: Getting UserForm Object giving its name
is it possible to have a function getting given a string indicating an Object's name then returning corresponding UserForm Object as a result?
Function foo(name as string) as Object
   dim Obj as Object
   ' code to do the job
   set foo = Obj
End Function


Have you made any attempt to do this? It's quite trivial to step through all the controls on a form Me.Controls and compare the name of the control to the input name. A function can return an object, just remember to use Set

The UserForms collection contains all loaded forms.  Most likely the form you want has not been loaded yet, and conveniently the Add method takes the name of the form as a string argument.  Leveraging this knowledge gives us the following code:
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim f As Object
   Set f = GetForm("UserForm2")
   f.Show
End Sub

Private Function GetForm(ByVal Name As String) As Object
   Dim f As Object

   'if already loaded, return it
   For Each f In UserForms
      If f.Name = Name Then
         Set GetForm = f
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
   
   'if not loaded, add it and return it
   Set GetForm = UserForms.Add(Name)
End Function

